# Why is the field of rational functions not Dedekind complete?

Tags: real-analysis, ordered-fields

The field of rational functions $F_{\mathbb{Ra}}$ in one variable is a classic example of a non-archimidean ordered field.

For an ordered field to be non-archimidean, it must not be dedekind complete (if a field were both ordered and dedekind complete, then it would be $\mathbb{R}$, which is archimidean).

---

I believe that I understand a counterexample to the claim that rational functions are archimidean:

Consider two members of $F_{\mathbb{Ra}}$, $g(x) = x$ and $f(x) = n$ for $ n \in \mathbb{N}$. When we assess whether $g(x)$ is larger than $f(x)$ -- or any two members of $F_{\mathbb{Ra}}$ -- we assess whether whether for sufficiently large $x$, $g(x)$ is greater than $f(x)$. In this example, it is true that no matter the member of $\mathbb{N}$ I select for $f(x) = n$, sufficiently large $x$ in $g(x)  = x$ will always exist that are greater than $n$. Thus, there is no way of ever making $f(x)$ larger than $g(x)$.

This is the "assessment" AFAIK

"We also have trichotomy: if $h \in F_{\mathbb{Ra}}$ and $h(x) \not = 0$, 
then either $h(x) > 0$ for all sufficiently positive x, or $h(x) < 0$ for all sufficiently positive $x$."

---

I wanted to learn why rational functions are not dedekind complete.

Dedekind complete: every nonempty subset $S \subset F$ which is bounded above has a least upper bound.

Comment: Repeat again what exactly the order on the space of rational functions is. You will quite probably find that your reasoning for comparing $x$ and $n$ is not correct.

Comment: er, a hint please? Nothing comes to mind!

Comment: This should be in the task description or the definitions it is based on. How would you sort, by that order, $2, 1+x, 1+2x+x^2$?

Comment: $1 + x$ is greater than $2$ for $x > 1$.  $x^{2} + 2x + 1$ to $1 + x$ for $x > 1$ as well. This is also transitive.

Comment: But is $x>1$? Remember that $x$ is an abstract algebraic object, not the placeholder for the argument of a real function. Or taken another way, the rational functions are pairs of finite sequences of coefficients, not "function" functions. The two easiest interpretations are that $x$ is an infinitesimal, or second that $x$ is infinite in the order.

Comment: I see what you mean. I wrote what I wrote, only because my instructor had written this comment, which I may have misinterpreted: "Say that a rational function h = f /g is positive if there exists M ∈ R such that h(x) is
defined and positive for all x > M. In other words, h is positive if, to the right of some
value M, the graph of h has no vertical asymptotes and stays above the x-axis."

Comment: What ordering scheme would you recommend, then?

Comment: I think the usual one is where $0<x<1/n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ is an infinitesimal. But you should use the order from the same source you got your question from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36931/discussion-between-muno-and-lutzl).

Answer (score 0):

Let $E:=\mathbb{Q}$. Clearly, $E$ is a Riesz space under the natural ordering of $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $A:=\{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, then $\emptyset \not = A \subseteq E$. Furthermore, we know that $\sup A=e$ (we know this result from real analysis; this gives that $A$ is a non-empty subset of $E$ which is bounded above), but $e \not \in E$, so $E$ is not Dedekind complete ($E$ being Dedekind complete requires that every non-empty subset of $E$ which is bounded above has supremum in $E$). This shows that the set of rationals is not a Dedekind complete space. We can use a similar argument, choosing appropriate functions, to show that the field of one-variable rational functions is not Dedekind complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is no least upper bound of the real numbers in the field you described,
Let $f$ be such that $f>r$ $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}$
then $f-1>r$ $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}$
and $f-1<f$ so there can not be a least upper bound.